# Nsight graphics debugging won't let application connect to the internet

Tags: debugging, opengl, curl, nvidia, nsight

I am debugging an application using Nsight Visual Studio Edition and while running the graphics debugging my application can't connect to the internet.

The game saves all it's information on the internet so it won't run without an internet connection(just goes to an error screen but I need to debug elements in game).

I have tried changing the port on which the monitor and the debugger work thinking that they block the application but it still doesn't work.

The application works normally when I'm not debugging using Nsight so it' nothing trivial like no internet connection or errors in the application.

The requests are made through cURL and that seems to fail to connect while debugging with Nsight.

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: Which version of Nsight, Visual Studio, and Windows are you using? Is your application compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Latest version of Nsight 3.1, Visual Studio 2008, Windows 7 x64 and the application is compiled for 32 bit.